# Erro illegal string offset 'key' cakePhP

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou começando a usar `CakePhp`, quando vou cadastrar algo, ele retorna os seguintes erros:

> Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'key'
> [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\SessionHelper.php, line 143]
>
> Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'message'
> [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\SessionHelper.php, line 167]

Porém cadastra no banco.

Comment: Qual é o código que gera o erro?

Comment: eu fiz o CRUD pelo bake no cmd, e na hora que vou cadastrar, editar ou apagar ele retorna esse erro. a função que da o erro é esta: public function flash($key = 'flash', $attrs = array()) {
  $out = false;

  if (CakeSession::check('Message.' . $key)) {
   $flash = CakeSession::read('Message.' . $key);
   CakeSession::delete('Message.' . $key);

   $out = '';
   foreach ($flash as $flashArray) {
    if (!empty($attrs)) {
     $flashArray = array_merge($flashArray, $attrs);
    }
    $flashArray['key'] = $key;
    $out .= $this->_render($flashArray);
   }
  } return $out;
 }

Comment: Silas, preste atenção, faça tudo o que digo nesta ordem e sem falhar nenhum dos itens: **1.** edita (clique no link acima chamado editar) a pergunta e fala exatamente como você fez, o passo a passo - **2.** informe a versão do PHP, **3.** informe a versão cakephp, **4.** informe se instalou algo a mais com o cakephp para o uso das Views. ... Somente informando isto poderemos ter uma ideia minima de como te ajudar.

Comment: 1. Criei um novo projeto no netbeans 8.2 e adicionei junto o framework do cakePhp, versao 2.10. dpois adicionei o plugin do bootstrap, fiz uma tabela para teste chamada usuarios. gerei o crud dela pelo cmd do  windows atraves do comando Console\cake bake all; 2. php versao 7.0.22; 3. cakePhp versao 2.10.3; foi instalado somente o plugin do bootstrap a mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema alterado a versão do *PHP* para 5.5